# Can I use IPv6 today?

Tags: networking, ipv6

My VPS (Virtual Private Server) provider offers unique IPv6 addresses much cheaper than IPv4, but what can I use it for? The VPS runs Debian 5.

I currently use the VPS for web hosting and running IRC clients and bots. I run Linux on all of my workstations that I use to connect to the VPS, but I do not have any external IPv6 addresses from my ISP:s.

Will I still be able to connect? Can I point any domain name to an IPv6 address? Would only IPv6 clients be able to visit the web site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. And yes. You CAN use IPV6 internally. You CAN provide your wewbsite with IPV6.

If you provide your website with IIPv6 ONLY, all people on IPV4 will not be able to access our website. Which means 99% of your potential visitors are off.

It is that simple.

Nice to prepare. Bad to use at the moment. At least exclusively.

> provider offers unique IPv6 addresses much cheaper than IPv4

If that is not for free, run. You should not get addresses, but a full network, and upon requst I think a /56 or something. That is what the specs say.

Comment: I checked more closely now, and it's a one time fee of about 10 cents (1 Swedish krona), but I only get allocated one IP address.

Comment: Change the host. My hoster gave me a /56 upon request. As they should. In general, IP Address specification does NOT say "turn out addresses" it says "turn out networks". That said, I do not run a server, so I have a router in between (it is a cluster of servers).

Comment: It's not bad to use it exclusively, it's mostly useless due to lack of forethought by IPv6 designers. Their only transition plan is the idiotic dual stack "solution."

Comment: Really? Depends what you do. Publish a website ONLY on IPb6 is iodiotic (not useless - plain stupid) because simply said there are very few people at the moment having acess to IPv6... thanks to providers and producers of end user routers.

Comment: Of course, depending on your target audience, having your site only on IPv6 could be an amazingly good way to keep out the riff-raff, so to speak.

Comment: @niXar You fail so hard at comprehending protocol stacks it's embarrassing.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/faq#etiquette

Comment: @Olipro: that was a very useful comment. Thank you for your input. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is on IPv6 and your workstations are on IPv4, they will not talk to each other unless you put in an IPv4-to-IPv6 **bridge** in between. Good thing is there are a number of different services that provide just that. [HE](http://ipv6.he.net/) is a common one. So is [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net).

Of course, you need to make sure that the VPS actually is connected to the Internet using IPv6 and it is not just for their own internal network and the packets actually get dropped at the edge.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I disagree with TomTom's answer; if you have an IPv6 only machine then you *will* be reachable via Teredo and 6to4, to suggest that everyone with only Native IPv6 can reach you is simply false.

In fact, on the contrary, you can actually leverage a technology such as 6to4, teredo (or a proper 6in4 tunnel) on a host of your own that *does* have IPv4 in order to provide proxying to the IPv6 only host, Anything is possible!